# Error transferring files from mainframe to RedHat Linux using FTPS

Tags: mainframe

I want to transfer a few files weekly from mainframe to a Linux server running RedHat using a batch (`JCL`) job using FTPS.

Linux server is configured with `vsftpd`.  Is it possible to send file from mainframe to linux using FTPS?

Getting this error while transferring the file from mainframe to Linux.

```
EZA1736I FTP
EZY2640I Using 'SYS1.TCPPARMS(FTPDATA)' for local site configuration parameters.
EZA1450I xxx FTP CS xxx
EZA1456I Connect to ?
EZA1736I host_name
EZA1554I Connecting to: host_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port: 21.
220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)
EZA1701I >>> AUTH TLS
234 Proceed with negotiation.
EZA2897I Authentication negotiation failed
EZA1534I *** Control connection with host_name dies.
EZA1457I You must first issue the 'OPEN' command
EZA1460I Command:
EZA1618I Unknown command: 'Atul'
EZA1619I For a list of the available commands, say HELP
EZA1460I Command:
EZA1736I Summer@123
EZA1618I Unknown command: 'Monsoon@123'
EZA1460I Command:
EZA1736I cd /home/Atul/
EZA1457I You must first issue the 'OPEN' command
```

Comment: Not sure what the quetion is. I don't know vsftpd explicitly. If this server follows the FTPS protocol, not SFTP, then I don't see why you shouldn't be able to connect from the mainframe. Firewall might be an issue.

Comment: Getting this error while transferring the file from mainframe to Linux. Not sure about the error -

Comment: Did you follow the [operator response instructions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=messages-eza2897i) for the EZA2897I message?

Comment: Review this link about setting up TLS for FTP and report back on your findings / issues  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=security-steps-customizing-ftp-client-tls   Unfortunately, the amount of data says generally the certificates are not being processed but more detail is needed to outline corrective action.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sending from the mainframe using FTPS to VSFTP is certainly possible. Both the client (z/OS in this case) and server (Linux in this case) need to agree on the encryption method to be used and I believe by default, z/OS has to trust the certificate for the server, which may involve importing the certificate bundle to a key ring that the batch job has access to. The job not having access to a keyring that trusts the chain for the server certificate would be my first guess.

I don't have experience with setting up the RACF keyring things, but I can say that people do successfully send us data every day from z/OS to our Linux server via FTPS.

Answer (score 0):

From your log you seem to be able to set up an unsecured connection to the FTP server. That's good.
`EZA2897I Authentication negotiation failed` indicates that the TLS-handshake did not complete successfully. Either the partners could not find a common TLS-version and/or ciphersuite or (that's the point I'd examine first) the certificate provided by the FTPs-server isn't trusted by the client user. To be sure you would have to capture and examine a TCP- or TLS-trace.

In a first step I would check the certificate provided by the FTP server and compare it to the trusted certificates in your security manager. In the case of RACF you would have to examine SITE-certificates and/or certificates in the user's keyring.